# change iframe language to its parent language workaround

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, lang

we have a website and embeded content in an iframe in one page at the same website domain

now we want to add weglot app for language, when we change the language no changes apply for the iframe

adding two language buttons for the website and the iframe is not the best practice at all

how could we apply our chosen language in both pages the website page and the iframe content?

Comment: Can't you adjust the iframe src to whatever differentiates the language in the main page?

Comment: i didn't get your point?